# 15.10 Full Terminal and application borders are black

Tags: command-line, 15.10

- My computer is showing black borders everywhere.
- Full Terminal is Black

[image: One of the shot]

Please note: I have tried changing themes. It is not theme issue.
Graphics : Intel® Sandybridge Desktop 
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G645 @ 2.90GHz × 2

Comment: Let me know any other information needed

Answer (score 0):

After some quick research, i found [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/fix-large-black-borders-around-header.html). It may solve your problem